# printing json from perl is incorrect

Tags: json, perl

Im trying to print out in json format info that I have gotten, I think if I show what I have that will better explain everything.

```
foreach ...{
    printer($versions);
}

sub printer
    {
    foreach ...{
         my $results = id_cards();

    my $toJsonResult = JSON::to_json($results);
    print $toJsonResult;
    }
}

sub id_cards
{
    my $returnData = [];
    for($x=1;$y < $vehicle->{'ROWS'};$x++ )
    { 
          my $data;
          $data->{year} = $vehicle->{$x}->{'YEAR'};  #there is more $data->repetativeness but not important to get the point
          push(@$returnData,$data);

          $y++
    }

return $returnData;
}
```

the json that is printed:

```
[{"year":"2004"},{"year":"2004"}][{"year":"2002"},{"year":"2000"},{"year":"1994"}][{"year":"2004"},{"year":"1955"}][{"year":"2004"},{"year":"1955"}]
```

This is very close to what I want but there is no separation of the json "objects"? (not sure what the term is) but it makes it not valid json. What can I do to put the years grouped accordingly but in valid json.

Comment: Where is `$data` declared? If it is a global, it will retain its value, throughout all the loops.

Comment: @TLP I added to my code, in the for loop in id_cards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the right idea in the `id_cards` sub:

```
sub some_function {
    my $return_array = [];
    foreach (...) {
        push(@$return_array, $some_result);
    }
    return $return_array;
}
```

Do the same thing in `printer`:

```
sub printer {
    my $return_array = [];
    # for ...
    return $return_array;
}
```

Then in the outermost `foreach` at the top of the file do the same:

```
my $results = [];
foreach (...) {
    push(@$results,printer($versions));
}
print JSON.to_json($results);
```

Only print once, at the last minute. JSON expects a fully formed data structure. If you don't give it everything then you can't expect it to know how to format it properly.

Of course, at this point, the function `printer` doesn't print anything. So it is misnamed. I would change its name to `card_collection` or something.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing *multiple* JSON texts in a loop. Each time you go around the loop, you print a new JSON text.

You should build your data structure in the loop, and then convert the whole thing to JSON afterwards.

e.g.

```
sub printer {
    my @data;
    foreach ...{
        push(@data, id_cards());
    }
    print JSON::to_json(\@data);
}
```

Comment: You're right, I made the change but not much has changed. It appears to be something with my arrayref or hashref I dont know, being new. With your suggested code now it prints `[][[{"year":"2004"},{"year":"2004"}]][[{"year":"2002"},{"year":"2000"},{"year":"1994"}]][[{"year":"2004"},{"year":"1955"}]][[{"year":"2004"},{"year":"1955"}]]` Any idea of what to do?

Comment: Then you're calling `printer` multiple times. So you also have the same problem higher up.

Comment: @ikegami wow youre correct. Ok I have put in my code but am unsure on how to return what i need so I can print my json from what printer gives me. Thank you so much for any help you can provide. I have been stuck on this forever!

Answer (score 0):

You're effectively doing the following:

```
my $result = [ { year => 2002 }, { year => 2003 } ];
my $toJsonResult = JSON::to_json($results);
print $toJsonResult;  # [{"year":"2002"},{"year":2003"}]

my $result = [ { year => 2004 }, { year => 2005 } ];
my $toJsonResult = JSON::to_json($results);
print $toJsonResult;  # [{"year":"2004"},{"year":2005"}]

my $result = [ { year => 2006 }, { year => 2007 } ];
my $toJsonResult = JSON::to_json($results);
print $toJsonResult;  # [{"year":"2006"},{"year":2007"}]
```

That creates a new JSON document for each result, and jams them all together on STDOUT.

You want to create one document that's an array of all your results, so you need to place your *all* your results in an array.

```
my @results

my $result = [ { year => 2002 }, { year => 2003 } ];
push $results, $result;

my $result = [ { year => 2004 }, { year => 2005 } ];
push $results, $result;

my $result = [ { year => 2006 }, { year => 2007 } ];
push $results, $result;

my $toJsonResult = JSON::to_json(\@results);
print $toJsonResult;  # [[{"year":"2002"},{"year":"2003"}],
                      #  [{"year":"2004"},{"year":"2005"}],
                      #  [{"year":"2006"},{"year":"2007"}]]
```

Comment: updated my code, how can i return the group from printer and print everything?

Comment: Since you want to call `JSON::to_json` just once, it needs to be outside the `printer` loop. You need to return the values to put the in the array and construct the array as I've shown you.